# Devexpress - LookUpEdit custom column

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a class bind to Devexpress' LookUpEdit and I want a custom column in format .. Is there a chance to format column? Or do I need to create property that will return me string in specified format and bind it to this property?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I don't need this functionality but I found [this](http://rashidkalady.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/custom-text-in-devexpress-lookupedit-control/) if someone will need to implement it. But still I think that read-only property might be a better solution.